# How to build Qwt on Windows

Tags: qt, windows-xp, qmake, qwt

Here's what I've done:

1. Downloaded qwt-4.2.0-setup-qt230nc.exe from sourceforge
2. Unpack to C:\Program Files\Qwt
3. Go to Qt Command Prompt
4. Run msvc-qmake.bat.
5. Get the [output](http://www.nopaste.pl/g3e).

Now the lib directory is created, but it's empty. Also tried opening VS project file, but it doesn't converse to VS2008, because there are no vcproj files. I also tried to do it qmake way:
`qmake qwt.pro` and then `make`, but it says make is not recognized. I figured that I could use mingw32-make, but I gave me a lot of compiler errors.

I was hoping I would use Qwt within QtCreator, but sadly failed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've come up with easy solution:

1. Open QtCreator.
2. Open project... -> C:\Program Files\Qwt\qwt.pro
3. Build.
4. ...
5. PROFIT!!!

Do I guess correctly it's valid way to do this?

Now I need to figure out how to marry it with QtDesigner since there is no Designer Plugin in here...

Comment: Sorry, but I think my solution is more comfortable.

Comment: Hello. I build it with debug and release. Now I have 2 folders (debug and release). What to do with it next? I didn't build any exaples. It only created obj files of them. Can you give me any hint?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio you must to do next steps (according to file "INSTALL"):

1. run console
2. change directory to directory where you installed QWT
3. type "qmake qwt.pro"
4. type "nmake"

You must be ensured that nmake.exe and qmake.exe in your PATH environment variable.

P.S. Easy way to add nmake.exe (its Visual Studio's make realization) is to run "tools/visual studio 2008 command prompt" from main menu of visual studio.

Comment: Here's my output: http://www.nopaste.pl/g3z
Looks like I lack g++... I got VS 2008 and QtCreator (installed with whole Qt SDK).

Comment: You need to go follow the instructions in Qt Command Prompt. Not the usual one :)